# Rails - Adding Custom Fields at runtime in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

You know how some bug trackers (and other software) allow you to add custom fields?

Typically this is done with a data structure that looks something like this:

```
  Items
----------
 ID | NAME | ITEM_TYPE_ID


 FieldDefinitions
---------------------------------------
 ID | ITEM_TYPE_ID | FIELD_NAME | FIELD_TYPE

 FieldValues
---------------------------------------
ID | FIELD_ID | ITEM_ID | VALUE
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this design in Rails.  There will be many models which I want to allow extending simple properties.

When I retreive an `Item` I'd like it to include a hash of the addition field values that have been defined for that model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like...?

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :field_values
  has_many :field_definitions, :through => :field_values

  def custom_fields_hash
    cfh = {}
    self.field_values.each |fv|
      cfh[fv.field_definition] = fv
    end
    cfh
  end
end

class FieldValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :field_definition
end

class FieldDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :field_values
  has_many :items, :through => field_values
end
```

Or, you could change

```
cfh[fv.field_definition] = fv
```

...to...

```
cfh[fv.field_definition.field_name] = fv.value
```

Comment: Using inject would probably be better form.  Like self.field_values.inject({}) { |memo, fv| memo[fv.field_definition] = fv } or similar.

Comment: This is what I was thinking I'd use... was wondering if there was a more "ruby" way to do this...

Comment: The usual way would probably not to use a hash at all and just use the generated association methods, but I guess there's a reason why you were particularly wanted a hash...?

Comment: I was thinking of   person.meta[:twitter] or something of the sort.  Feel free to educate me on something cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Friendly ORM](http://friendlyorm.com/). It allows you to work with mysql without a schema. It was inspired by this [blog post](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql) about how Friendfeed uses mysql to store schemaless data.

Friendly would replace ActiveRecord, although you can use ActiveRecord models next to Friendly models pretty easily.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but a cool find nonetheless.  +1

Comment: If you do consider schema-less data, you might want to look at using a document database like CouchDB or MongoDB (see http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper for a webcast about using MongoDB and the MongoMapper gem in a rails app; Ryan Bates is awesome btw).

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely interested in that.  I'm on Heroku, which currently won't work with MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to have your `FieldDefinition` records belonging to **different** models (for example, a column `item_id` that points to either a `SqueekyToyItem` or a `BalloonItem`) then what you want is a polymorphic association.

It basically allows you to have an `item_type` column (beside your `item_id` column), which then specifies the actual type of item it points to.

There's a heading “Polymorphic associations” in the documentation for [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I do intend to have them on many models, but they will all inherit from Item (or whatever my base class ends up being)