# Gem for taxonomy / user-defined fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, custom-taxonomy

Is there an existing gem for adding user-defined field functionality to an existing Ruby class?

Two examples of the type of gem/solution I'm looking for are:

- [Rails custom meta model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255150/rails-custom-meta-model)
- [Rails - Adding Custom Fields at runtime in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200565/rails-adding-custom-fields-at-runtime-in-activerecord)

...and ultimately I'd like to allow users to build their own taxonomy of user-defined objects, through the web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've use [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) and evaluated [taxis](https://github.com/mikefarmer/taxis) for building taxonomies.

I'm not sure what you mean by "user-defined field functionality", though; do you mean dynamic attributes on a model?

One option is simply serializing a hash, although you'd likely need to add type information based on the user's choices.

Since you likely have a limited number of types available, (string, int, date, etc.) then you're probably better off creating thin models around them (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.) that contain the value and the name of the dynamic "column" and using normal associations, e.g., `has_many :string_vars`.

Comment: Yes, dynamic attributes on a model. That is, allowing the user to add attributes to an object, specify the type (integer, string, date, etc.) and have those stored alongside the objects themselves. No need to store the additional attributes as extra columns, as it's not my goal/desire to modify the schema programmatically.

Comment: @normalocity Meh. Serialize a hash, but you'd likely have to add the typing yourself.

Comment: Huh - so you think just serializing a hash and storing that instead would be a way better way of doing this, which results in a single table column, and (if I understand correctly) simpler DB queries as a result.

Comment: @normalocity Moved to answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. This sounds like the right approach to me. I have a similar set of objects doing something very similar, but the jump to the hash serialization is going to make it much cleaner!

Comment: @normalocity I think if you want to query on values in the hash you're going to run in to issues.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that while I was out to lunch, but I think I might be able to solve that via virtual attributes - i.e. dynamically adding methods to the models classes based on the custom field names, thereby enabling sorting, filtering, etc. It's questionable whether, from a speed standpoint, that implementation would actually be efficient, but I think I'm going to give it a shot and just see how it performs. Might not actually be that bad for the functional benefit it provides.

Comment: @normalocity But different instances will have different dynamic values. Wouldn't you need to essentially load them all in, add your dynamic methods (and the return values), then use AREL or something? I don't see how adding methods will help.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's already an accepted answer, this post is mostly just for future reference... Sounds to me like you're looking for an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Saying, for example, you have a User - which would be entity (call it an entity type), you have an attribute (say a text field attribute, or attribute type, called "name"), and then a value that you want to go into that text field to attach to a user. Every user (entity) should be able to have an attribute (name) associated with it. That could be accomplished with an EAV model.